# .net UIAutomation simple example in C++

Tags: microsoft-ui-automation

I am going through [UIAuomation Clients API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in .Net and have to use C++ instead of C#. This is because the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) function is only available in C++ and seems to be the most reliable method of sending mouse clicks to any application (same problem as this question: [How to manipulate a control without any pattern implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230985/how-to-manipulate-a-control-without-any-pattern-implemented)).

Right now I am struggling with the C++ version of UIAutomation API because of the lack of documentation on msdn. Can someone tell how to create a PropertyCondition using [CreatePropertyCondition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), UIA_NamePropertyId and "Windows Media Player".

```
char *name = new char[30];
strcpy(name, "Windows Media Player");
VARIANT vt;
vt.vt = VT_CARRAY; // This is probably wrong
vt.pcVal = name;
hr = g_pAutomation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, vt, &condition);
if(!SUCCEEDED(hr)){
    printf("Cannot createpropertycondition in getWMP\n");
    return hr;
}
```

I am always going inside the `if` condition. the `g_pAutomation` variable is working fine, I am able to get the RootElement fine.

Also a link to a simple tutorial/sample (in C++) will be really useful.

Thanks

Comment: Little bit offtopic, but... have you looked at something like http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ or white ?

Comment: I am trying not to use any third-party code and stick only to .NET's abilities. I did see some other open source stuff too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
VARIANT vt;
vt.vt = VT_BSTR;
vt.bstrVal = SysAllocString(windowName);
```

There is very hard to navigate the MSDN but I managed to find an example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff625913(v=vs.85).aspx